# Accessing and editing pandas.DataFrame via index/column entry

Tags: python, pandas

i want to access a pandas DataFrame elementwise by giving the row and the column; seems simple to me, but researching didn't give the answer. I got this far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=np.random.randn(3,3)
index=np.linspace(0.1,1,3)
columns=np.linspace(2000,3000,3)

pdf=pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

I found `pdf.ix` to access, but it gives me a `NaN` and i can't edit the entry:

```
 pdf.ix[['0.55'],['2500']]
Out[16]: 
      2500
0.55   NaN

pdf.ix[['0.55'],['2500']]=2
KeyError: "['0.55'] not in index"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You shouldn't use strings but actual numerical values: `pdf.ix[0.55, 2500]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax is:

```
pdf.ix[0.55,2500] = 42
```